# How to know if a user has a privilege on Object?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, privileges

I would like to know if a user has a privilege on an object or not.

I'm working on SQL Developer.

When I query manually the table **DBA_TAB_PRIVS**, I get all the information needed.

However, I need this information to be used in some triggers and functions.

So, I'm writing PL/SQL function that will return 1 if a role has the privilege and 0 otherwise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HAS_PRIVILEGE_ON_OBJECT(rolename      IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   objectname    IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   objectowner   IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   privilegename IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  output NUMBER;
  BEGIN

    SELECT count(*) INTO output
      FROM dba_tab_privs
     WHERE grantee = rolename
       AND owner = objectowner
       AND table_name = objectname
       AND privilege = privilegename;

    IF output > 0 THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END has_privilege_on_object;
```

The function doesn't compile and says :

> ORA 942 : table or view does not exist.

The user connected has access to the view DBA_TAB_PRIVS since I can query it, but when trying to automate it using a function. It doesn't work.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll wager that you have privileges on `dba_tab_privs` via a role, not via a direct grant.  If you want to use a definer's rights stored function, the owner of the function has to have privileges on all the objects granted directly, not via a role.

If you disable roles in your interactive session, can you still query `dba_tab_privs`?  That is, if you do

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> select * from dba_tab_privs
```

do you get the same ORA-00942 error?  Assuming that you do

```
GRANT select any dictionary
   TO procedure_owner
```

will give the `procedure_owner` user the ability to query any data dictionary table in a stored function.  Of course, you could also do a direct grant on just `dba_tab_privs`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `table_privileges`:

```
select * from table_privileges;
```

This does not require any specific rights from your user.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have access to DBA_TAB_PRIVS through a role.  So, executing SQL works fine, but roles are not enabled in the PL/SQL context, so, compilation fails.

Try:

```
grant select on sys.dba_tab_privs to <user>;
```

and that should take care of it.